# How to convert a javascript animation to video output on client side

Tags: javascript, linux, video, ubuntu, video-capture

Is there any simple way to create video output of js animation without editing the js at all.
If that is absolutely possible, how I can I edit the js to create images or videos of the animation. This has to be really really fast, since I want to do some real time processing on the animation.

I am using Ubuntu on the desktop.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VLC (http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) to capture your desktop into a movie file.

VLC allows you to apply filters o you may stream the video to postprocessing software.

Comment: Am thinking of using ffmpeg directly to capture. Its not just filters, I actually want to run an algorithm on it. Thanks.

Comment: If you also use Selenium you may actualy have an automated process :)

Answer (score 0):

*Really fast* and Javascript .... don't really go well together.  Depending on the quality of animation you want, it is anywhere from *slow* to "Egads, we need a thousand machines to render this 5 minute scene"

You'd have to render a imagine, save the image, then render the next.

You'd be *far* better off using a system, platform and software suited for the job.